# Como colocar um aplicativo para rodar em background quando for fechado?

Tags: node.js, electron

Estou criando uma aplicação em **Node.Js** usando **Electron** e preciso que ela continue executando em background quando for fechada e *se transforme em um ícone do aplicativo próximo ao relógio do computador* para o usuário ter acesso. Porém não encontrei referências para fazer esta tarefa, então a pergunta é:

**Como colocar um aplicativo para rodar em background quando for fechado?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta definir o evento `close` do objeto `BrowserWindow` para que ele esconda a aplicação ao invés de fechá-la:

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 380,
    height: 600,
  })

 win.on('close', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    win.hide()
 })
```

Mais informações [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980563/3496534).

Comment: Excelente. Tem alguma ideia de como colocar um ícone da aplicação próximo ao relógio da barra de tarefas?

Comment: Dê uma olhada na classe [Tray](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md#class-tray), você pode passar o caminho para a imagem que será usada como ícone ao instanciá-la.